# block collision issues on a 2D map tiled java

Tags: java, collision

I'm having problems with wall collision. Basically I want my player to stop whenever it collides with a block.
Here's what I did so far:

Keylistener set up:

```
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
                pressL = true;  

            }

            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
                pressR = true;  

            }

            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
                pressU = true;  

            }

            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
                pressD = true;  

            }
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){

                pressL = false; 

            }

            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){

                pressR = false;


            }

            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W){

                pressU = false;


            }

            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S){

                pressD = false; 


            }
        }   

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

        }
    });
```

Player's movement:

```
public void playerMovement(){ 
   player.horizontalMovement(0);
   player.verticalMovement(0)

   map.horizontalMovement(0);   
   map.verticalMovement(0);     

   if(pressR && !pressL && !pressU && !pressD){
         if(!east){
         toggleRight();                 
         }

         if(collision("east"))
         east = true;                               
     }          

   if(pressL && !pressR && !pressD && !pressU){
        if(!west)
        toggleLeft();                    

        if(collision("west"))
        west = true;
   }

   if(pressD && !pressU && !pressR && !pressL){
        if(!south)
        toggleDown();

        if(collision("south"))
        south = true;
   }

   if(pressU && !pressD && !pressL && !pressR){ 
        if(!north)
        toggleUp();

        if(collision("north"))
        north = true;

   }
}
```

Here's where the collision test is:

```
public boolean collision(String loc){

    Rectangle pR = player.getBound();
    Rectangle pM = map.getBound(0, 0);

    if(loc.equals("east")){     
        if(pR.equals(pM)){
            if(west)                
            return false;               

            if(!west)               
            return true;                
        } west = false; south = false;north = false;                            
     }

    if(loc.equals("west"))      
            if(pR.intersects(pM)){
                if(east)                
            return false;   

            if(!east)               
            return true;        
        } east = false; south = false;north = false;
    }

    if(loc.equals("south")){
        if(pR.intersects(pM)){
                if(north)               
            return false;


            if(!north)              
            return true;    


        } north = false; west = false;east = false; 
    }

    if(loc.equals("north")){
        if(pR.intersects(pM)){
                if(south)               
            return false;


            if(!south)              
            return true;                        

        } south = false; west = false;east = false; 
    }

    return false;
}
```

I set up my code likes this to avoid being stuck whenever I collide with a block I'm testing with. It works but there are a lot of bugs I'm encountering. One example is sometimes I get stuck, or the player can pass through the block with pressing the vertical with the horizontal keys. I'm having problems figuring out the proper algorithm for this. And by the way the direction is based on the viewer's direction not the player's.

Can someone share with me a descent way of do it? Thanks.

Comment: Try to be more specific in your question and focus more on the particular problem.

Comment: Hi, my problem is that the code that I set up is not doing what I wanted it to do. like for example, when the player is going right and bumps into a block the collision executes but when I press W going up the player gets stuck and I have to press S so it can go up and vice versa. I want the player to detect every side of the specified tile to be a blocked tile so player can't walk through it in every direction. I'm looking for a descent code that can show me how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

For player and walls (blocks) create `Shapes` (e.g. `Polygon` can be used). The use `Shape's` methods

```
public boolean intersects(double x, double y, double w, double h);
public boolean intersects(Rectangle2D r);
```

Or you can create `Areas` from the `Shapes` and use

```
public void intersect(Area rhs)
```

Comment: @StanuslavL, can you give me a sample code on how this can be done? I'm new to java. Thanks!

Comment: @krazaz don't use KeyListener use KeyBindings